# Fluid element that needs to match the height of side nav

Tags: html, css

I have a layout I need some help with.  What I'm trying to do is come up with a layout where the main content is a fluid 100% width based on the window size however, the left nav which is fixed matches the height of the main content.  I've included an image.  Getting this to be static is obviously easy.  My issue is how do I achieve what I'm looking for if I want it to be fluid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68cS7/